# JQ is iterating over each word in a given key, as opposed to each instance of the key

Tags: bash, loops

When I run the code below, it's iterating over each word in the key `.serverParams` instead of each instance of the key. (Echoing the line is not my ultimate intent, but just using it so I can see the output of each iteration)

```
for i in $(jq -r .servers[].serverParams ./servers.json); 
    do echo "$i"; 
    done
```

**I can get my intended result with the following but it seems clunky:**

```
for k in $(jq '.servers | keys| .[]' ./servers.json); 
    do jq .servers[$k].serverParams ./servers.json; 
    done
```

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: @Pointy are JSON's not Javascript files?  I can remove the tag.

Comment: JSON is a serialization format *based* on JavaScript, but it's not JavaScript.

Comment: OK so `jq` is a JSON access tool, got it.

Comment: So keep or remove the tag? 

Comment: Without seeing what your JSON content looks like it's really hard to see what your asking. "Each instance of the key" is in particular not really clear.

Comment: Your jq is fine. Your **bash** code is the problem.

Comment: `for item in $(thing-that-generates-lines)` is wrong; it string-splits the output of `thing-that-generates-lines` on all characters in IFS, not just newlines, and then expands them each as globs (so a `*` that's its own word will be replaced with a list of filenames in the current directory). Use a [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) `while read` loop instead. BTW, this issue is closely related to [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: @Pointy `{
  "servers": [
    {
      "Key1": "Some Value",
      "Key2": "Some Value",
      "Key3": "Some Value",
      "serverParams": "Some Value"
    },
    {
      "Key1": "Some Value",
      "Key2": "Some Value",
      "Key3": "Some Value",
      "serverParams": "Some Value"
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll re-write as a while loop.